# Leaflet map won't fit bounds

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to fit a map to bounds defined by a 2D array.  I keep getting the error `Error: Bounds are not valid.  leaflet.js:5:21909` even though the markers are added to the map and are valid coords.

```
var map = L.map('map', { zoomControl:false });
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
}).addTo(map);



map.setView([0, 0], 2);

var markers = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(markers);


function drawResults(){
    // get offer keys
    var offers = new Array();
    var articles = [];


    offersRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {        
        var offerKeys = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
        for (var i=0; i<offerKeys.length; i++){
            var offer = snapshot.val()[offerKeys[i]];           
            var lat = offer.lat;                
            var lng = offer.lng;
            console.log(lat);// outputs 33.2321
            console.log(lng);// outputs 101.1234
            offers.push([lat, lng]);
            var marker = L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(markers);
        }

    });
    map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());

    }
    console.log(offers);    

}

drawResults();
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: 
Console logs

```
35.0721909  app.js:350:13
-106.48798399999998  app.js:351:13
35.0526641  app.js:350:13
-78.87835849999999  app.js:351:13
```

Comment: Why do you need `group`? Shouldn't it be `map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds())`? `markers` itself is a `FeatureGroup`.

Comment: @cartant  You're right -- that's how I originally had it and it was giving me the same error, so I decided to try something.  Editing code to show without pointless extra featuregroup; I get the exact same error.

Comment: Your comments state that `lat` and `lng` output particular values. How many points do you have? If more than one, are they coincident? What's returned by `getBounds`?

Comment: @cartant  There are two points -- just added them to my question.  I thought only lines could be coincident?  I don't know what it means for points to be.  ```console.log(markers.getBounds())``` doesn't print anything to the console...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to move the call to `map.fitBounds` into the callback, as the `once` method (which looks like a Firebase API call) is likely asynchronous:

```js
offersRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
    var offerKeys = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
    for (var i = 0; i < offerKeys.length; i++) {
        var offer = snapshot.val()[offerKeys[i]];
        var lat = offer.lat;
        var lng = offer.lng;
        offers.push([lat, lng]);
        var marker = L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(markers);
    }
    map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());
});
```

If it's called outside the callback, there won't be any markers in the feature group and the group's bounds won't be valid.